# mysql_install_db Generic Message Why?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

For whatever reason my MySQL server crashed and I had to use mysql_install_db initialise mysql data directory.
This installation worked. However I have to start the server manually every time it reboots.
I have tried to run `sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults` so that it should start automatically at boot time but the MySQL server does not start.
One thing I can remember is that after finishing installation using mysql_install_db there was this ***generic*** message

> "To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
>   support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system"

According to some quarters the right place for the system **(Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-77-generic x86_64))** is **/etc/init.d/** but the problem at hand the location of 
support-files/mysql.server. I have tried `$ sudo find / -name mysql.server` and outputs nothing. Where is **support-files/mysql.server** located.

MySQL version is mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.50, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thousand ways to kill a rat.The mysql server can be started manually by running the following commands:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
sudo service mysql start
```

Automate these series of commands by putting them in Ubuntu ***rc.local file***. A crontab at boot up may execute the commands prematurely.